# error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 1

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, docker

i was containerizing my .Net + React.js application but during the process I have encountered an unexpected error. I got myself acquainted with similar posts but none of the solutions solved my problem. Since the build log is quite long I have placed in pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/PhfYW3zm

The dockerfile which I am using comes from the official documentation, and that's why it comes to me as a surpise that it does not work:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-tools-react?view=vs-2022

The Dockerfile itself:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApp/WebApp.csproj", "WebApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApp/WebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApp"
RUN dotnet build "WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleting the `npm install` tags from .csproj as suggested in this thread https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9593 by user PKLeso resolved the problem.

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
```

This will delete frontend from your container completely if I remember correctly. However if you want to remain it within container just make sure that `npm install` on your frontend leaves no errors. Beacuse otherwise MSB3073 error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If there are dependency conflicts in the react app, for example after an upgrade of react to to the latest version, and because of that `npm install` invoked on the ClientApp does not run but `npm install --force` does run then in the `.csproj` add `--force` to the

```xml
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
```

line, so it becomes

```xml
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install --force" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it could still be of interest, but actually I found it useful to use the `ContinueOnError="true"` xml attribute.

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" ContinueOnError="true"/>
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --configuration production" ContinueOnError="true" />
```

This way every exception that npm will thrown (like the vulnerability messages) will be ignored and the build will continue, installing npm packages and building frontend node assets.