# Unable to publish the artifact for .NET Core on Azure Devops (pipeline)

Tags: asp.net, angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

Unable to publish the artifact for .NET Core, I can able to build but can't publish on Azure Devops.

- Frontend: Angular
- Backend: .NET Core 6
- SQl : MSSQL server
  [image: Console error message]
  [image: App service error message]

Front code : Angular,
Back end : dotnet 6,
Sql : MSsql Server

Comment: I think there is an error because the npm install is executing and it is causing the error. 

Are you using docker?

You could go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356033/error-msb3073-the-command-npm-install-exited-with-code-1

Comment: not using docker

Answer (score 0):

Given that your project could be restored correctly, I suppose that you could add a `--no-restore` to your `dotnet publish` argument and test again.

**Updated on 1/2**

======================================================

I suppose there are multiple possible caused for your current issue of `https 500.30`. You could visit [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#50030-in-process-startup-failure) to troubleshoot.

**Additionally**,

1.Check your hosting model. Confirm that whether it's IN Of Process or Out of Process. You can check the configuration in you csproj file. if you using In of Process, try to change it to
`<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>`

2.If you are deploying `win-x64` app and try to have it published using an Application Pool that supports `32-bit` apps, you will need to make them match-up.

3.Check in portal.azure.com for your web-app whether it is running correctly.

4.Go to portal.azure.com check you app console, and try to manually start your project with `dotnet ServerApp.dll`.

==========================================================

**Updated on 1/9**

Hi devendar

Check this doc [Bad Gateway errors in Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502) for further troubleshoot.

Comment: i tried it, but still its not published

Comment: I tried --no-restore but no use same error

Comment: @devendar, any update? I have updated my answer and you could check if it helps.

Comment: Hello Mr. Ceeno, Thank you so much, the build (CI) got successful, and I did deployment in the app service its also successful but while browsing the app service it shows an error message, can you please help me? I have updated Error screenshots in my question

Comment: @devendar I updated some more, the issue of `http 500.30` could be resulted from multiple causes. You could look into [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67211060/http-error-500-30-asp-net-core-5-app-failed-to-start) for more potential workarounds.

Comment: Hello Ceeno, I updated new screenshots in my question, please check it once.

Comment: @devendar check the doc I shared for reference